# lvalue and rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I am having a hard time understanding lvalue and rvalue references. Look at this code example

```
#include <iostream>

//Returns r-value
int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
//Return l-value
int & Transform(int &x) {
    x *= x;
    return x;
}

void Print(int &x) {
    std::cout << "Print(int&) L value ref" << std::endl; 
}
void Print(const int &x) {
    std::cout << "Print(const int&) const l value ref" << std::endl;

}
void Print(int &&x) {
    std::cout << "Print(int &&) r value ref" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    //x is lvalue
    int x = 10;
    
    //ref is l-value reference
    int &ref = x ;
    //Transform returns an l-value
    int &ref2 = Transform(x) ;
    //Binds to function that accepts l-value reference
    Print(x);

    Print(ref);
    Print(ref2);

    //rv is r-value reference
    int &&rv = 8 ;
    
    //Add returns a temporary (r-value)
    int &&rv2 = Add(3,5) ;
    //Binds to function that accepts a temporary, i.e. r-value reference
    Print(3);
    Print(rv);
    Print(rv2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I got

```
Print(int&) L value ref
Print(int&) L value ref
Print(int&) L value ref
Print(int &&) r value ref
Print(int&) L value ref
Print(int&) L value ref
```

I can (I guess) understand the first 4. However for the last two I am printing `rv` and `rv2` which I thought were r-values so why are they being passed to the Lvalue ref function?

Answer (score 3):

`rv` and `rv2` are actually **l-values**, because they have names assigned to them. They both have r-value reference as their *type*.

The 1st `Print()` takes a const-reference, which can bind to both lvalues and rvalues.  To call the 2nd `Print()` instead, you will have to use `std::move()` to convert `rv` and `rv2` into r-values, eg:

```
Print(std::move(rv));
Print(std::move(rv2));
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/IiSugg)

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

> The functions that accept rvalue reference parameters [...] are selected, by overload resolution, when called with rvalue arguments. If the argument identifies a resource-owning object, these overloads have the option, but aren't required, to move any resources held by the argument.

In your code example, namely

```cpp
//rv is r-value reference
int &&rv = 8 ;

//Add returns a temporary (r-value)
int &&rv2 = Add(3,5) ;
```

<strike>the `&&` aren't r-value references but [universal references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). That means the type could be either an rvalue or an lvalue, whenever is appropriate. In your case, the compiler selected an lvalue.</strike>

You need to force the category to be an rvalue by performing `std::move`:

```cpp
Print(std::move(rv));
Print(std::move(rv2));
```

I've linked the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to `std::move` previously but I've remembered it by the  phrase "convert an lvalue to an rvalue". Here's another example:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Salut";
    std::vector<std::string> v;
 
    // uses the push_back(const T&) overload, which means
    // we'll incur the cost of copying str
    v.push_back(str);
    std::cout << "After copy, str is " << std::quoted(str) << '\n';
 
    // uses the rvalue reference push_back(T&&) overload,
    // which means no strings will be copied; instead, the contents
    // of str will be moved into the vector. This is less
    // expensive, but also means str might now be empty.
    v.push_back(std::move(str));
    std::cout << "After move, str is " << std::quoted(str) << '\n';
 
    std::cout << "The contents of the vector are {" << std::quoted(v[0])
              << ", " << std::quoted(v[1]) << "}\n";
}
```

```
After copy, str is "Salut"
After move, str is ""
The contents of the vector are {"Salut", "Salut"}
```

Correction:
`int&&` is indeed an rvalue reference. `auto&&` is a universal reference, which in your question, is irrelevant. However, it's useful to know they *exist*.

Comment: `int&&` is an rvalue reference, not a universal reference.

Comment: if it is a rvalue reference why doesnt it call the rvalue ref print?

Comment: rv2 is an lvalue. It has a name so when it's used in an expression ie: as an argument to a function it is seen as an lvalue. See @Remy's answer.